# Define a list of optional keys for Typescript Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to type an object which can only have keys 'a', 'b' or 'c'.

So I can do it as follows:

```
Interface IList {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
}
```

They are all optional! 
Now I was wondering if this can be written with `Record` in just one line

```
type List = Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>;
```

The only issue is that all keys need to be defined. So I ended up with

```
type List = Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>>;
```

This works,  but I can imagine there is a better way to do this without Partial. Is there an other way to make the keys optional inside Record ?

Comment: "I can imagine there is a better way" - no; I think your composition approach is the best answer (and surely the intended solution by the TypeScript designers)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

There is no way to specify the optionality of members of `Record`. They are required by definition

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T; // Mapped properties are not optional, and it's not a homomorphic mapped type so it can't come from anywhere else.
};
```

You can define your own type if this is a common scenario for you:

```
type PartialRecord<K extends keyof any, T> = {
  [P in K]?: T;
};
type List =  PartialRecord<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>
```

Or you can define `PartialRecord` using the predefined mapped types as well:

```
type PartialRecord<K extends keyof any, T> =  Partial<Record<K, T>>
```

Comment: "There is no way to specify the optionality of members of `Record`"... Are you certain about this? `Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>` seems to operate exactly this way, from what I can tell. Was this something that was changed since this answer was made?

Comment: @KOVIKO `Partial` is a different type, the question was if you can specify it for `Record` itself. The last code snippet shows exactly the ability to compose `Partial` with `Record` to get the effect of `PartialRecord`

Comment: Ah, I see now that they specifically asked how to do it without Partial and I read too much into the first sentence. mb

Comment: How about `Record<string, string>`? It does not require specifying all possible strings. Why is there an inconsistency?

Comment: Is it possible to specify which fields are optional and which are not for a Record?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for `Object.values` or `Object.entries` -- both of your proposals give the key type as `T | undefined` when it should be `T`. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 78):

You can create the partial version of your `List` type:

```
type PartialList = Partial<List>;
```

And you could do it all on one line if you don't want the intermediate type:

```
type PartialList = Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c', string>>;
```

You might decide that, in the end, the most expressive for your future self is:

```
type List = {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
}
```

Comment: except it is likely that it is not `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` and that the list is much longer and may well change over time. Would you still make that recommendation if there were 50 entries that change every few months? It is a genuine question... I have about 15 entries and am firmly on the fence at the moment!

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods If you have a list of 50 entries and if they could change every few months, you need to think about how you are going to use them. If they come from a database and the entries are all strings you could simply replace them with string instead of writing them out. But if you're planning to use these variable names in your code (not dynamically), you can create a list of them for type checking.

Answer (score 30):

Looks like in new versions of typescript you may do the following

```
type YourUnion = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';   
type ObjectWithOptionalKeys = Partial<Record<YourUnion, string>>
const someObject: ObjectWithOptionalKeys {
  a: 'str', // works
  b: 1 // throws
}
// c may not be specified at all
```

Comment: Looks just like the answer from @fenton https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276876/1950957

Comment: Indeed, sorry. I guess I just have some difference in naming but overall it's the same answer, indeed.

Answer (score 15):

It's also possible to do it this way:

```
type List = { [P in 'a' | 'b' | 'c']?: string }; // The `?` makes the keys optional
```

Examples:

```
const validList1: List = {
  a: 'hi'
}

const validList2: List = {
  b: 'hi',
  c: 'there'
}

const validList3: List = {
  a: 'oh',
  b: 'hi',
  c: 'there'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the `Partial<Record<List, string>>` solution,
there is perhaps a more obvious option to consider.

Instead, you could store your data in a map.

```
const map: Map<KeyType, ValueType> = new Map();
```

From a functional point of view there's not much difference.
It really depends on the context whether this is a viable alternative or not.

Comment: Can you update with an example using map?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
type Key = "a" | "b" | "c"

type List = { [key in K]?: string }
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that all (valid) solutions to the question also allow empty Records to be passed. If you want to enforce at least a specific key you need:

```
interface Foo {
  a: A,
  [key: string]: B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this meet your requirements:

```js
type SomeType = Partial<Record<keyof IList, string>>
```

You can update IList to define new valid keys. And they will be optional.