# Is there a way in Typescript to instantiate a Record<K, V> by assignment in a generic function<T> where: T extends an object-type and K = keyof T?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, record, keyof

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
interface A {
    a: number
    b: number
}

function f<T extends A>() {
    const x: Partial<Record<keyof T, string>> = {a: 'generz'}
    console.log(x)
}
```

But, when compiling (using `tsc v4.9.3`) I get this error message:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ a: "generz"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>'.
```

I don't understand why and **I would like to have an explanation on this error.** If `T extends A` then `keyof T` is a superset of `keyof A` (containing at least `'a'|'b'`), so the `{a: 'generz'}` would be legal independently of `T`? Am i missing something?

---

I've found out, that creating a custom `PartialRecord` type (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276792/define-a-list-of-optional-keys-for-typescript-record)) like this:

```
type PartialRecord<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]?: T
}
```

And then changing the type of variable `x` to `PartialRecord<keyof T, string>` , like this:

```
const x: PartialRecord<keyof T, string> = {a: 'generz'}
```

Compiles the code without complaining.

---

### Update 2022-11-25

This would be equivalent code and it compiles too:

```
const x: Partial<Record<keyof T, string>> = {}
x.a = 'generz'
```

Although is not what i'll like to do.

---

### Update 2022-11-29

**What I'm asking is NOT "how to make it work in alternative ways", but is "why it doesn't work that way"**, since I expect it to work. Otherwise I'd just do `{a: 'generz'} as Partial<Record<keyof T, string>>` (or worse `as any`).

And if it wasn't clear: the code is nothing more than the minimum necessary to reproduce the error. So its purpose is not to make sense or do anything useful.

Comment: Doesn't extending a type essentially mean you're narrowing it?

Comment: @Nick - *Equal to* or narrowing, yeah.

Comment: So does this fail because the narrowing is ambiguous in this case?

Comment: @Nick any thoughts? Do you think that could eventually the problem be worth becoming an issue on the Typescript repository? just in case nobody answers

Comment: You can ask there. My instinct is this is expected behavior, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to be able to explain it.

Comment: @Nick thank you, I'll eventually try next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting a `Record<keyof T, string>` inside a `Partial` leads to a level of abstraction which can not be properly understood by the compiler. Both `Record` and `Partial` are implemented as [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which can not be fully resolved when a *yet unspecified* generic type is supplied.

While the logic behind your assignment might be sound, it requires higher level reasoning by the compiler about the implications of nesting `Record<keyof T, string>` inside a `Partial`. Yet, it seems to be inable reason about this type *at all* leaving it essentially *opaque*. No expression would identify this type as a valid assignment target leaving only a type assertion as a workaround.

There have been multiple open issues about these *higher order* type problems like [#43846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43846) where `Partial` being wrapped around `Omit` lead to the same error or [#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) where an intersection of
`Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> & Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, K>>` was not assignable to `T`. The compiler would fail to properly evalaute the generic types leaving them opaque, even though these operations a reasonable and mostly sound to us.