# How to create Record with dynamic string union property names that are optional?

Tags: typescript, types, index-signature

I want to define an object type where the property names are pre-defined, but also optional.

I want to create the equivalent of the below longer syntax, but is there a way to make it dynamic with optional properties so I could easily add / remove those options?

```
interface List {
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
  three?: string;
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to make the following invalid code work.

```
type options = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
type List = Record<options, string>;

// Valid
const MyObjOne: List = {
    one: 'Value 1',
    two: 'Value 2',
    three: 'Value 3',
}

// Invalid
const MyObjTwo: List = {
  one: 'Value 1',
  two: 'Value 2',
}
```

But TypeScript gives this error for `MyObj` [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBA9mwEsYDsDOUC8UDkKLagB8dgB3GA47YACwCcJ8BuAKFEigBkFVhMoAShADGMOgBMAPHEQpUAGii86CZAHMAfKxYB6HVABqAQwA2CcS1Fo+AWRAB5AEYAre8ggAuLjz5YA3ixQQbDuXtjGJgCu0ACM2PKBwWQwYRHRUABM8YlBtAyeOGnQAMzZAL4suvoAksgAbqbmlnK2Di4AKuRe3Lz8AUF4qabpcQm5XYXD0FkJZUA)

`Property 'three' is missing in type '{ one: string; two: string; }' but required in type 'List'.`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276792/define-a-list-of-optional-keys-for-typescript-record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the utility type [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype):

```
type List = Partial<Record<options, string>>;
```